# Center the last row in a LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

In a `LazyVGrid`, I show data coming from the server (here I'm using the alphabet as an example), and my goal is to show the last row in a center instead of `leading` if the last row contains less than 3 items. Is it doable?

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
   let alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    let preference = [
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible())
        ]
    var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: preference) {
        ForEach(alphabet, id: \.self) { value in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemIndigo))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                Text(value.description)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Goal:

[image]

Comment: should there be only 3 columns  even when the device get landscape orientation ?

Comment: @Yodagama Thanks for asking! For now, let's just think that the app only supports portrait mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load every Cell **lazily**.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    let preference = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: preference) {
                ForEach(alphabet.dropLast(alphabet.count % 3), id: \.self) { value in
                    Cell(value: value)
                }
            }
            
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(alphabet.suffix(alphabet.count % 3), id: \.self) { value in
                    Cell(value: value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

extracted your Cell view for reusability

```
struct Cell: View {
    let value: String
    var body: some View {
        print(value)
       return ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemIndigo))
                .cornerRadius(16)
            Text(value)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're in the last row and apply a translation effect. If there are 2 items in a row, translate them by width / 4. If there are 3 items in a row, translate them by width / 6 and so on.

[image]

```
someView
.transformEffect(
    .init(
        translationX: isLastRow ? metrics.size.width / 4 : 0,
        y: 0
    )
)
```